# Фонетика. Звуки

Tags: фонетика

1) Скажите, пожалуйста, в каких случаях в абсолютном начале слова может стоять звук "и" с призвуком "э"? Наблюдается ли это в слове "ежевичный" (jиэжыэв'ич'ныj)?

2) Когда ставится звук [и], под которым дуга?

3) Кто в грамоте горазд... 
Будет ли звук "в" в транскрипции менятся на "ф"?

Answer (score -1):

В слове "ежевичный" первым стоит йотированный звук [е] и является созвучием [йе], следующий звук мягкий согласный [ж], далее однозвучное [е], мягкие звуки [в], [и], твёрдые [ч], [н], гласная [ы] и согласный звук [й]. Складываем звуковое слово [йежевичный]. Не удивляйтесь это в моей новой более точной интерпретации звуков.

Comment: Мягкого звука ж в русском языке не существует, также как звука [е].